# Flutter Drawer Navigation

Tags: flutter, flutter-navigation, flutter-drawer

I have a list of Screens in a custom drawer.

Screen 1,
Screen 2,
Screen 3

What is the proper way of navigating from Screen 1 to Screen 2 on push of a button. Currently, I am losing the hamburger (the drawer button) option when I push or push replace.

The code I have was not written by me and I do not have access to the person who wrote the code.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Just use the standard navigation:

```
TextButton(
  onPressed: (){
    Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Screen2()));
  }
  child: 
    //child goes here
)
```

Comment: The problem is that I am losing the drawer menu. Should I include drawer menu in every screen within Scaffold?

Comment: @Ganesh no it's not necessary, some devs put the drawer in the home page only, and you can push and pop screens from the drawer or by any other actions, e.g. button click, swipe...